# Restriction map of Galois groups

Tags: galois-theory

I am trying to understand the meaning of the restriction map of Galois groups. Suppose $F\subset L_1\subset L_2\subset K$ are fields such that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are Galois over $F$. There is, I am told, a "restriction map" Gal$(L_2/F)\rightarrow$Gal$(L_1/F)$. What I assume this means is that we restrict the action of $\sigma\in$ Gal$(L_2/F)$ to the field $L_1$, which would then be an automorphism of $L_1$. However, I am also aware that Gal$(L_1/F)$ is a quotient of Gal$(L_2/F)$, but I'm not sure if this is relevent. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand what is the question. I assume you are talking about finite Galois extensions. Yes, if you restrict an automorphism from $Gal(L_2/F)$ to $L_1$ then you will get an element in $Gal(L_1/F)$, this follows from the fact that $L_1/F$ is a normal extension.

Comment: Yes, $L_1$ and $L_1$ are finite extensions (not necessarily $K$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $\sigma \in Aut(L_1/F)$ and $L_2/ L_1$ is algebraic then (applying $\sigma$ to the coefficients of $L_1$-minimal polynomials) you can extend $\sigma$ to an isomorphism $L_2 \to \sigma(L_2)\subset\overline{L_2}$ fixing $F$
- If $L_2/F$ is normal then $\sigma(L_2) = L_2$ so that $\sigma \in Aut(L_2/F)$
- Conversely if $\sigma \in Aut(L_2/F)$ and $L_1/F$ is normal then $\sigma(L_1) = L_1$,

Thus the restriction map is surjective $Aut(L_2/F)\to Aut(L_1/F)$ which proves that $$Aut(L_1/F)  = Aut(L_2/F)/\ker(\sigma \to \sigma|_{L_1}) = Aut(L_2/F)/Aut(L_2/L_1)$$

Comment: Does this can extend to infinite extension?